# Input multiple files in a web form one after the other using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, file-upload, input

I'd like to input files from a folder into a website. I was able to input one file but I want to input a file from a folder, run the online job, then input another file from the same folder until all the jobs are submitted. Here's my code for one file input.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "http://www.example.com"

email = "name@email.com"
data = open ("file.txt","r").read()
title = data[16:22].replace("|","")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path_to/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
emailid = driver.find_element_by_name("email_address")
emailid.send_keys(email)
job = driver.find_element_by_name("job_title")
job.send_keys(title)
submit = driver.find_element_by_name("protein_sequence")
submit.send_keys(data)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("input_button").click()
print submit.page_source
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using mechanize, something like this `br.back()` and repeat the process.